# git: Find out whose code gets deleted

Tags: git

Since we can [track the commit history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265040/how-to-count-total-lines-changed-by-a-specific-author-in-a-git-repository) in a Git repository to look out for addition/deletion of code, I would like to understand how to keep a track/count on authors whose code gets deleted most.

This could indicate that the code they wrote in the first place was not that good (or that the features they built are not needed anymore).

Comment: This could also indicate that those guys are having the brighter ideas quickly implemented or scaffolded in the source code that get replaced over time by enhanced/actual implementations from their less skilled colleagues (as one simple example of positive impact). Counting lines of codes in either way to get an idea of coder's efficiency proves to be a very poor metric in almost all cases.

Comment: or it shows they wrote the most code to begin with, or that they write the most verbose code.... Or that they refactor more often, or a bunch of other things that make this metric completely and utterly pointless.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/q/4592866

Answer (score 0):

See the github [difflame](https://github.com/eantoranz/difflame),
written in python and described as:

> **Description**
>
> Show the output of git diff with the additional information of git
>   blame for added/removed lines so that it's 'trivial' to find out who
>   did what.
>
> **Output**
>
> Format Lines that remain the same or that were added will indicate when those lines were added to the file. Lines that were
>   removed will display the revision where the line was removed. When
>   it's not possible to pinpoint the revision where it was deleted, the
>   last revision where that line was present is reported instead (as
>   reported by git blame --reverse). When this happens, a percentage sign
>   (%) will be used as the prefix of the deleted line (instead of the
>   usual -).

An example of the output of difflame, using the parameter `--no-hints` to minimize
the output:

```
diff --git a/difflame.py b/difflame.py
index ff65112..ec21fcd 100755
--- a/difflame.py
+++ b/difflame.py
@@ -51,7 +51,7 @@ REVISIONS_INFO_CACHE=dict()
 9d2e8d4 (Edmundo Carmona Antoranz 2017-02-02 22:11:09  51  51) 
 18ecda8 (Edmundo Carmona Antoranz 2017-02-15 00:42:18  52  52) '''
 cb52676 (Edmundo Carmona Antoranz 2017-02-15 01:01:06  53  53) caches to save:
-cd789a5 (Edmundo Carmona Antoranz 2017-02-15 01:10:15  54    )     - reverse blamed files # TODO consider cleaning this when we finish processing a file
+cd789a5 (Edmundo Carmona Antoranz 2017-02-15 01:10:15      54)     - reverse blamed files
 cb52676 (Edmundo Carmona Antoranz 2017-02-15 01:01:06  55  55)     - diff of files when analyzing revisions (merges and so on)
 cb52676 (Edmundo Carmona Antoranz 2017-02-15 01:01:06  56  56) 
 18ecda8 (Edmundo Carmona Antoranz 2017-02-15 00:42:18  57  57) BLAMED_FILES_CACHE[originating_revision][final_revision][filename] = lines
```

A script could be written to process this output, extract the author-names
from the deleted lines into a temporary text-file, then sort and count the lines
(using for example `sort | uniq -c | sort -nr`).

Answer (score -1):

From StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828874/generating-statistics-from-git-repository/1829302#1829302

> Beside [GitStats](http://gitstats.sourceforge.net) (*git history statistics generator*) mentioned by
> [xyld](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828874/generating-statistics-from-git-repository/1828903#1828903), written in Python and requiring Gnuplot for graphs, there is
> also
>
> - [gitstat](http://mirror.celinuxforum.org/gitstat/) ([SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gitstat)) project (*web-based git statistics interface*), written in PHP and Perl,
> - [Git Statistics](http://repo.or.cz/w/git-stats.git), aka gitstats (*metrics framework designed to gather statistics on git repositories*), written in Python, result of
>   [git-statistics project at Google Summer of Code 2008](http://sites.google.com/site/alturin2/gsoc2008) This
>   is not a web app
> - [gitinspector](http://code.google.com/p/gitinspector/) Is a rather new, CLI based Python tool for generating nice reports
> - [Hercules](https://github.com/src-d/hercules) - native app without dependencies, written in Go, which specializes in advanced analysis
>   types.